# Laravel 5.3 storing 'a' char into database

Tags: laravel, save

I'm trying to save a string with 'á' and it does not work. I can save other chars like ñéíóúÉÍÓÚÁ.

Any Help?

```
$name = "ñéíóúÉÍÓÚÁánnnnnnnn"
$client->name = $name;
$client->save();

//saves only "ñéíóúÉÍÓÚÁ" in database (MySql)
```

Comment: Does the name of the client have a maximum size in your database? If the name is too long, it will  get truncated just like in your exemple

Comment: check the size of name column in table

Comment: Try to add this line before your code and check if it works: `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: I think is a laravel bug because it occurs only with 'á' and not for example with 'Á' or 'é'.  I tried mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); and dont works. I have enough space (varchar 255), if I change the order of chars my string is truncated where is 'á'

Comment: And if you try with just _á_ alone, does it work?

Comment: it does'n work. I'll try to insert using php utf8_encode and php utf8_decode. Thank you!